# Using Oracle sequence to insert log id into 2 tables from jdbc?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, sequences

I am using oracle sequence for inserting log id into tableA as follows,

```
String SQL_PREP_INSERT = "INSERT INTO tableA (LOG_ID,USER_ID,EXEC_TIME) VALUES"
            + " (logid_seq.nextval, ?, ?)";
```

Then getting the recently inserted value,

```
String SQL_PREP_SEL = "SELECT max(LOG_ID) FROM tableA ";

stmt = con.prepareStatement(SQL_PREP_SEL);
stmt.execute();
ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
if (rs.next()) {
logid = rs.getInt(1);
}
```

And inserting it into tableB,

```
String SQL_PREP_INSERT_DETAIL = "INSERT INTO tableB (LOG_ID, RESPONSE_CODE, RESPONSE_MSG) VALUES"
                + " (?, ?)";

        stmt = con.prepareStatement(SQL_PREP_INSERT_DETAIL);
        stmt.setInt(1, logid);
        stmt.setString(2, respCode);
        stmt.setString(3, respMsg);
        stmt.execute();
```

Is there a way to generate sequence in Java instead of Oracle and insert into both tables at once, instead of selecting from tableA and inserting into tableB?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, selecting the `MAX(log_id)` is not going to give you the same value that `logid_seq.nextval` provided.  Assuming that this is a multi-user system, some other user could have inserted another row with a larger `log_id` value than the row you just inserted before your query is executed.

Assuming that both `INSERT` statements are run in the same session, the simplest option is probably to use the `logid_seq.currval` in the second `INSERT` statement.  `currval` will return the last value of the sequence that was returned to the current session so it will always return the same value that was generated by the `nextval` call in the first statement.

```
INSERT INTO tableB (LOG_ID, RESPONSE_CODE, RESPONSE_MSG) 
  VALUES( logid_seq.currval, ?, ? )
```

Alternatively, you could use the `RETURNING` clause in your first statement to fetch the sequence value into a local variable and use that in the second `INSERT` statement.  But that is probably more work than simply using the `currval`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String QUERY = "INSERT INTO students "+
               "  VALUES (student_seq.NEXTVAL,"+
               "         'Harry', 'harry@hogwarts.edu', '31-July-1980')";

// load oracle driver
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

// get database connection from connection string
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:sample", "scott", "tiger");

// prepare statement to execute insert query
// note the 2nd argument passed to prepareStatement() method
// pass name of primary key column, in this case student_id is
// generated from sequence
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(QUERY,
        new String[] { "student_id" });

// local variable to hold auto generated student id
Long studentId = null;

// execute the insert statement, if success get the primary key value
if (ps.executeUpdate() > 0) {

    // getGeneratedKeys() returns result set of keys that were auto
    // generated
    // in our case student_id column
    ResultSet generatedKeys = ps.getGeneratedKeys();

    // if resultset has data, get the primary key value
    // of last inserted record
    if (null != generatedKeys && generatedKeys.next()) {

        // voila! we got student id which was generated from sequence
        studentId = generatedKeys.getLong(1);
    }

}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30394077/oracle-awr-high-sql-parse-calls-but-0-executions/42384485#42384485 - there is a problem with this solution