# MyBatis SQL parsing

Tags: sql, mybatis

In our AWR report we saw some "select * from TABLE" sql with high number of parses but 0 executions. Can someone please help me why these statements gets parsed. We do not have this SQL statement in application code. There is insert statement present for the table in application code but not "select * from table".

We are using mybatis 3.4.6

Regards,
Vijay Maske

Comment: Are you sure that query is run from this specific application? I may be coming from another app that is connecting to the same Oracle database.

Comment: I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30394077/1261766). In any case, this may have nothing to do with MyBatis. ;)

Comment: @TheImpaler Thank for reply. There is no another app which uses this table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be due to OJDBC7 jar which trigger select * from TABLE if we need generated ID back in POJO after inserting it in table